# Insert into multiple tables (one to one relationships) with Linq queries and SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sqlite, windows-store-apps

I have three classes: Tab, Webpage, and base. My Tab class holds a Webpage object. So something like this:

```
public class Tab : Base
{
   public Webpage webpage {get; set;}
   //other code
}

public class Webpage : Base
{
   public string url {get; set;}
   //other code
}

public class Base
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   //other code
}
```

I am trying to use linq queries to insert a Tab object however when i do dbConn.Insert(myTabObj), it would return an error when trying to insert Webpage. Now I know I could serialize it and store inside the table.

However, I am wondering if there is a way to automatically add the Webpage to a webpage table and store the id of that webpage in the tab table.

edit: Or would it be possible to somehow "look" inside the Webpage object and just store the url in the Tab table. But when retrieving it would store the url in a Webpage object again.

Comment: A better option will be not to store it in DB , Assign an id to your page and insert Url in front of that id which will direct or link your page . However what is your requirement will decide the final answer so if you can elaborate a bit more your requirement.

Comment: Sorry about that, did not mention that my implementation was a little more complicated. For the purposes of this question I made the example a little more simpler. I am also keeping track of navigation history for each tab and storing page title and what not. I would like this to persist after the app has closed therefore I am using a sqlite-db to store the information.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the `Tab` and `Webpage` classes are correctly designed and linked using the O/R designer. You would need to set up foreign key constraints so that the `id` is recognized by Linq-to-SQL.

Walkthrough: Creating LINQ to SQL Classes (O/R Designer)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384428.aspx

You can then use the InsertOnSubmit function to schedule insertion of the new objects into the two tables.

```
YourDBDataContext dataContext = new YourDBDataContext();
...

Webpage page = new Webpage();
page.id = "p1";
page.url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
dataContext.InsertOnSubmit(page);

Tab tab = new Tab();
tab.id = "t1";
tab.webpage = page;
dataContext.InsertOnSubmit(tab);

dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```